# linux: is data written to a file guaranteed to be visible to other processes?

Tags: linux, file, linux-kernel

If I use `write(2)` to write to a file from one process on Linux and afterward `open(2)` and `read(2)` in another process, am I guaranteed to see the data I wrote without a call to `fsync(2)` or `close(2)`?

(Please ignore the possibility that the filename was unlinked or overwritten or that the system rebooted or that another process wrote data. And assume that I've correctly established an edge between the write and the read.)

I understand that the data isn't guaranteed to be persisted on disk, but is it guaranteed to be visible to the second process?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Or are you just asking for the mechanics of it? If there is no programming problem, then this question is offtopic here and better suited for [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: The problem is guaranteeing visibility of data, which is a question of programming APIs.

Comment: If writing to a file didn't guarantee that other processes could read it, what would be the point of files?

Comment: Yes clearly this *should* be the case, I'm just asking for documentation that proves it.

Comment: It may have been unclear if you didn't read the bottom paragraph that I'm talking about writing without syncing or closing. I've edited the question to make this clearer now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [posix spec for `write`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/write.html) lays this out clearly:

> If a read() of file data can be proven (by any means) to occur after a write() of the data, it must reflect that write(), even if the calls are made by different processes.